# How to plot this network graph with nodes in a circle and labels outside the nodes in R?

Tags: r, visualization, igraph, ggraph

I need to plot a gene network graph like this. I tried igraph package and the labels are on the nodes. Any idea how to plot this? Or should I use other packages instead?

[image]

This is my R code

```
obj.graph <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Omega, mode = "upper")
  l <- layout_in_circle(obj.graph)
  plot(obj.graph, layout = l, vertex.size = 5)
```

This is the output
[image]

Comment: Can you include a minimal reproducible example by sharing a sample of your data or some similar data using `dput()`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Probably this link could help for the graph visualization https://r-graph-gallery.com/311-add-labels-to-hierarchical-edge-bundling.html